# What is sparse model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso, regularization, ridge-regression

I am currently learning about Ridge and Lasso Regression, which leads me to learn about L1 and L2 regularization. There's a phrase saying `L2 Regularization doesn't result in sparse model` and `L1 regularization can result in sparse models with few coefficients`.

I know what sparse matrix means, a matrix with very few non-zero elements (hope I am not wrong about it) but I am not able to understand what a `sparse model` means. I tried to search about it on google but didn't find any satisfying answer. I am seeing this term a lot now, so It will be great if you can help me understand this.

I am not a math guy and so please be soft and use less terminology while answering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall what L1 and L2 regularization do: they drive the parameters towards small values, zeroes in a perfect case. A sparse model has many parameters zeroed out by regularization. You can implement it to actually use the sparse data structures for the parameters to save memory and compute.

Comment: "You can implement it to actually use the sparse data structures to hold the parameters to save memory and compute." -Didn't get this line

Are you saying that after applying l1 or l2 many features (parameter) will become zero(approx) and the model with many zeroed parameters is a sparse model right? Which then can be stored in any sparse data structure. Also what is sparse data structures

Comment: @DarkstarDream sparse vector holds only non-zero elements saving space. Dot product with such vector means multiplying only the non-zero elements because all the others are zeros when summing , so less operations. But this is a technical comment, sparse model is just one with zeroed out parameters.

Comment: So can I just conclude that a sparse model is a model with many zeroed parameters resulted from the operation of L1 or L2 regularization?

Comment: @DarkstarDream yes, it’s a model which has sparse parameters.